# Pandas dataframe column value dependent on dynamic number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe that looks something like this:

| user | current_date | prior_date | points_scored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2020-10-01 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2020-10-01 | 4 |
| 2 | 2021-01-21 | 2020-10-21 | 4 |
| 2 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-02-01 | 4 |

The `prior_date` column is simply `current_date - 3 months` and `points_scored` is the number of points scored on `current_date`. I'd like to be able to identify which rows had `sum(points_scored) >= 8` where for a given `user`, the rows considered would be where `current_date` is between `current_date` and `prior_date`. It is guaranteed that no single row will have a value of `points_scored >= 8`.

For example, in the example above, I'd like something like this returned:

| user | current_date | prior_date | points_scored | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-01 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2020-10-01 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-01-21 | 2020-10-21 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-02-01 | 4 | 0 |

The third row shows `flag=1` because for row 3's values of `current_date=2021-01-21` and `prior_date=2020-10-21`, the rows to consider would be rows 2 and 3. We consider row 2 because row 2's `current_date=2021-01-01` which is between row 3's `current_date` and `prior_date`.

Ultimately, I'd like to end up with a data structure where it shows distinct user and flag. It could be a dataframe or a dictionary-- anything easily referencable.

| user | flag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |

To do this, I'm doing something like this:

```py
flags = {}
ids = list(df['user'].value_counts()[df['user'].value_counts() > 2].index)
for id in ids:
    temp_df = df[df['user'] == id]
    for idx, row in temp_df.iterrows():
        cur_date = row['current_date']
        prior_date = row['prior_date']
        temp_total = temp_df[(temp_df['current_date'] <= cur_date) & (cand_df['current_date'] >= prior_date)]['points_scored'].sum()
        if temp_total >= 8:
            flags[id] = 1
            break
```

The code above works, but just takes **way** too long to actually execute.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, performing loops on large data can be quite time consuming. This is where the power of numpy comes into full play. I am still not sure of what you want but i can help address the speed
Numpy.select can perform your if else statement efficiently.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

condition = [df['points_scored']==5, df['points_scored']==4, df['points_scored'] ==3] # <-- put your condition here
choices = ['okay', 'hmmm!', 'yes'] #<--what you want returned (the order is important)
np.select(condition,choices,default= 'default value')
```

Also, you might want to more succint what you want. meanwhile you can refactor your loops with np.select()